# Scraping: Logging in headers are encrypted: how to send credentials?

Tags: authentication, post, web-scraping, encoding

I'm trying to log in to a website to send message with a python program.
However, the form data does not include clearly my credentials.
Here is the google developer console of the post

`form_data:`

`i: jxypuxqi-37ugeyuz;li=lv:142487;u=https://www.uwkotinleuven.be/fr/login;r=;t=;res=1280x720;z=-120`

I'm not sure how  to encode my credentials so that it registers me, and use a `requests` Session to keep track of my cookie.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Are you sure? I can see the credentials being sent just fine: https://i.imgur.com/p8ElWZE.png

Comment: @abdusco  How did you get the clear information? Are you looking at this through another browser than Chrome ?

Comment: That screenshot was from Firefox, but it works with Chrome too https://i.imgur.com/u4PvumD.png

Comment: @abdusco Woaw... I was filtering by XHR on the Network Tab, and for some reason the login_check request is labelled as text/html (Other) Any idea why that is ? Neverhteless, thank you so much!

Comment: Because that endpoint returns plain old HTML response. It's not an XHR/AJAX endpoint. That's why it's listed under that category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is submitted to `https://www.uwkotinleuven.be/fr/login_check`

[image]

Here's a how you can login using `requests.Session`. You need to extract CSRF token from the login page before you can submit the form.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
res = s.get('https://www.uwkotinleuven.be/fr/login')
res.raise_for_status()
token = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser').select_one('[name="_csrf_token"]')['value']

res = s.post('https://www.uwkotinleuven.be/fr/login_check', data={
    '_username': 'lalala@lalala.com'
    '_password': 'lalalalalala'
    '_csrf_token': token
})
res.raise_for_status()
# do something with the response
```